# Will this code lead to an object not being disposed?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, dispose

Say I have the following code:

```
 SPList promo1List = site.WebApplication.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList("promotions");
```

Will this lead to the SPSite object `Sites[0]` not being disposed?  I ran [SPDisposeCheck](https://web.archive.org/web/20150104075839/http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com:80/SPDisposeCheck/) against my code and it came up with a bunch of warnings about the above.

According to their [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160212041116/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx#SPDisposeCheckID_230): `SPSiteCollection[] indexer returns a SPSite object which needs to be disposed.`

Is this accurate or is this just a false positive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this code leads to memory leak.
I prefer to use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557362.aspx) (or [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for 2007 sharepoint) page every time, when I doubt if object should be disposed. According section `SPSiteCollection [ ] Index Operator` you **must** dispose SPSite object.

So, in order to correct dispose SPSite in your example, you need to use this code:

```
using (var mySite = site.WebApplication.Sites[0])
{
    SPList promo1List = mySite.RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList("promotions");
    //no need to dispose RootWeb, because the dispose cleanup for RootWeb is handled 
    //automatically by both SharePoint Foundation and SharePoint Server.
}
```

Comment: So would throwing a `using` around the `promo1List` declaration make everything dispose correctly?

Comment: please, refer to my update

Comment: Interesting. So it's not possible to dispose of the site object without declaring it on its own?

Comment: I don't know another way...

Comment: Well you could call promo1List.ParentWeb.Site.Dispose(), but adding the using as Kai suggest is a way better solution